# Async Bound Services

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to develop a way of a lot of apps (my apps) will sync to the cloud, I'm thinking of using AIDL for Creating a Service, this will be our main App, and every other app that want's to go to internet to fetch some data, post some data, etc. will travel trough that Service, I've done the IPC Connection between an Activity and also an Android Service. This is the method signature:

```
void doSomeAction(String testData, ServiceCallback callback)
```

Which ServiceCallback it's also defined on it's own AIDL File. But for some Reason, the callback it's not being called. Why is this happening?, When there's a connection to Internet, it fetches the String result and post it back to the Callback, which lives on the Client App, but nothing it's being called, why?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys, I wasn't calling a method from my code. Using a callback in the Service, works like a charm!!!